# How to determine number of rows in data, and use that value in defining a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In my macro there is a line:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A86893")
```

but the final cell number (86893), which is the total number of rows in my data, should be changed every time the macro is run. I need this macro since my amount of data increases every, but up until now I've had to change the address manually.

Is it possible put a formula instead of a cell number into the range definition, something like:

```
A2:A(counta(b:b))
```

where the formula `counta(b:b)` gives me the total number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you simply have to construct the string which give the range's address. In your case, you could do something like:

```
Range("A2:A" & CStr(Evaluate("=CountA(B:B)"))
```

To define the range you want to fill.

As an additional word of advice, you should really try to avoid using `Select`-statements when defining your ranges. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

To find the last value in your range, use this simple snippet -

```
Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Now you can use it in your range like `Range("A2:A"&lrow)`